# Monodevelop: Could not launch ASP.NET web server. The xsp4 web server cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mono, monodevelop, xsp

I run **OpenSuse 13.1** and I've encountered an error for MVC3 Empty application that I want to start from Monodevelop.

**Versions:**

- monodevelop: 4.2.2
- mono: 3.2.3
- xsp: 3.0.0.0

These packages were updated, I had the same problem with default OpenSuse 13.1 packages.

Could I somehow get more details about the error message?

Thank you,
Martin

Comment: you mean the command is not found?

Comment: Complete message:Could not launch ASP.NET web server
The xsp4 web server cannot be found. Please ensure that it is installed. It looks like the command is missing, but xsp4 is located on PATH, if I try it on command line.

Comment: type this command: `which xsp4` to see if the bin file exists.

Comment: did you start the server before running the application?

Comment: I run xsp4 manually and monodevelop reported: 'Port is already used.'. So that I closed xsp4 and monodevelop has started to work :) Thanks

Comment: Try installing it [again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34872143/2404470)