# ASP.NET web server cannot be launched and Mono environment not be switched

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mono, xsp

I am running [one of the latest versions of Monodevelop](http://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=home:tpokorra:mono&package=monodevelop-opt) on Linux Mint which used to work before I formatted my drive and made a fresh install. When I build my project it builds fine, but when I try to run it I get the following message:

> Could not launch ASP.NET web server.
>   The xsp4 web server cannot be found. Please ensure that it is installed.

I have xsp4 and xsp4-base packages installed. I found [in a question and answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360841/monodevelop-doesnt-find-xsp4-web-server-although-it-is-installed-running) that I need to switch the Mono runtime to make it able to find xsp4.

When I go to Edit > Preferences > Projects > .NET Runtimes I see the options `Mono 3.10.0 (Default)` and `Mono 3.10.0 (/usr)`. Unfortunately, when I switch to the `/usr` one (the one I need and should work) I get the same error as above that the web server cannot be found. And now the weird part: when I look again in the .NET runtimes options I see that is has switched the default back to the original one.

[image: The problem visualised.]

The switching back to another default only happens after I press F5 and try to build the solution (both with release and debug).

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: What is in `/usr/bin/xsp`?

Comment: @abatishchev Nothing.

Comment: So nothing in `/usr/bin/xsp4` too?

Comment: I do have `/usr/bin/xsp4`. It is not a directory but an executable.

Comment: It's probably a script, try `cat /usr/bin/xsp`. Or run it from a terminal

Comment: `cat /usr/bin/xsp4` gives `#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/xsp4.exe" "$@"`

Comment: Try `./usr/lib/mono/4.5/xsp4.exe` (and make sure it exists).

Comment: @abatishchev `-bash: ./usr/lib/mono/4.5/xsp4.exe: No such file or directory`... Now what? :-)

Comment: Try reinstall the xsp4 package. You have it "installed" but files are missing.

Comment: Also search for xsp4.exe. Maybe you need just to update script/path.

Comment: I am reinstalling the packages now. The `xsp4` one said `You have an incomplete /etc/xsp4/debian.webapp
 * To fix it, you need to install at least one package for xsp4 (like asp.net-examples)`, which I did.

Comment: Same problem as before, I tried find `xsp4.exe` and update the `/usr/bin/xsp4` script. But it said: `find: `xsp4.exe': No such file or directory`.

Comment: Hmm now I *did* find a `xsp4.exe` (it seems `find / xsp4.exe` is not the right command?). And `./usr/lib/mono/4.5/xsp4.exe` works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64736/discussion-between-user2609980-and-abatishchev).

Comment: I answered in that, please take a look

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In case we're running an [ASP.NET application on Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/) using [Monodevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/) for the first time, we may receive the below error:

[image: Could not launch ASP.NET web server]

In some cases, the problem is incorrect installation of [`xsp4`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/web/mono-xsp4) server.

Install it using:

`sudo apt-get install mono-xsp4`

This solved the above error.

**Optional:** get it from **Ubuntu software center** by searching for `xsp4`

**Extra:** For Arch (or based like Manjaro...) use `yaourt -S xsp`.

[image: mono-xsp4 in Ubuntu software center]

[source](http://xameeramir.github.io/solve-asp-net-error-on-mono/)

Comment: PLUS: For Manjaro and Arch use `yaourt -S xsp` .

Comment: @EduardoLucio Can you suggest your inputs as [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34872143/edit)